# Access another project over an xmlns reference

Tags: c#, wpf, xml-namespaces

I am using a custom calendar control made by someone else (under the GNU-GPL, of course) that I loaded into my solution. So how can I create a xmlns reference to it to use the calendar control? Also, they have different namespaces.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [XAML Namespaces and Namespace Mapping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747086.aspx):

```
xmlns:custom="clr-namespace:SDKSample;assembly=SDKSampleLibrary"
```